# MySql select JOIN issue. Just not sure what to do

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tabels (shown in the pictures) the first is a pages table (`cvl_pages`) the second is the `mysettings` table.

On the my settings table you will see columns like: `fav1`, `fav2`, `fav3`, `fav4`, `fav5`, `fav6` -- the integers in these fields correspond to the `Page_ID` found on the `cvl_pages` table.

I am trying to write a select statement that will select `Page_ID`, `Page_Title`, `function` from the `cvl_pages` table WHERE `PAGE_ID` = fav 1 thru 6.

I then need to create variables for the page title/function that corresponds to `fav1`, `fav2`, `fav3`... etc.

I am having a hard time putting it together in my head...without creating a separate SELECT statement for each "fav"

I guess I am asking for some help creating just one select statement that will give me the correct page title and function for each of the `fav` fields.

[image]

[image]

thanks!!!!

Comment: @GolezTrol: That's not very nice, especially to a new SO user, and this is probably their own website.  It may be funny, but the point is that SO is expected to be civil.  Read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @mellamokb I didn't mean to offend anyone, nor to appear uncivilized. I just misread the url, and thought it was funny. I'd even consider it a cool and daring name for a designer website. I've read in the FAQ: "Treat others with the same respect you’d want them to treat you." and "Bring your sense of humor.". I think I did both.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Hey I understand, no hard feelings, just the wrong person could be offended by that.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to join each different fav, but you can do that in one query:

```
select 
  s.*, /* or more specific fields you need from s */
  f1.Page_Title as Page_Title1,
  f1.function as function1,
  f2.Page_Title as Page_Title2,
  f2.function as function2,
  f3.Page_Title as Page_Title3,
  f3.function as function3,
  f4.Page_Title as Page_Title4,
  f4.function as function4,
  f5.Page_Title as Page_Title5,
  f5.function as function5,
  f6.Page_Title as Page_Title6,
  f6.function as function6
from 
  mysettings s
  inner join cvl_pages f1 on f1.Page_Id = s.fav1
  inner join cvl_pages f2 on f2.Page_Id = s.fav2
  inner join cvl_pages f3 on f3.Page_Id = s.fav3
  inner join cvl_pages f4 on f4.Page_Id = s.fav4
  inner join cvl_pages f5 on f5.Page_Id = s.fav5
  inner join cvl_pages f6 on f6.Page_Id = s.fav6
```

Comment: wow, i'm not gonna lie...im lost. I don't see mention to the actual table name "mysettings"....I am still trying to learn backend programming. Do you think you can provide a little more detail...as I am not sure how the above statement can work. SORRY!

Comment: Is it named `mysettings`, sorry, I thought it was just `settings`. I made some modifications and hope it's clearer now.

Comment: To clear it up. The `s` and `f1` to `f6` are *aliases* to the tables `mysettings` and `cvl_pages`. This way, you can keep your query more compact, and use the same table more than once. The latter is needed to join the pages table on each of the favs in `mysettings`.

Comment: In my query I use `inner join`, which means that avery `favX` should contain an actual `Page_ID` or that record is not returned at all. If you want to return any record from `mysettings` and want to return empty values for every `fav` that does not match a page, you can change `inner join` to `left join`. Lot of text, but it will make sense as soon as you try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do a simple join? something like:

```
SELECT Page_ID, Page_Title FROM cvl_pages p join mysettings s 
    on p.Page_ID in (s.fav1, s.fav2, s.fav3, s.fav4, s.fav5, s.fav6)
    where s.User_ID = 43;
```

Comment: i think this would work, but how do I create a variable for each page_title? I need them to correspond to each fav. something like:
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
  {
    $sideBar1 = $row['Page_Title.fav1'];
    $sideBar2 = $row['Page_Title.fav2'];
    $sideBar3 = $row['Page_Title.fav3'];
    $sideBar4 = $row['Page_Title.fav4'];
    $sideBar5 = $row['Page_Title.fav5'];
    $sideBar6 = $row['Page_Title.fav6'];
  }

Answer (score 0):

Right in that case, you should use GolezTrol's answer, but use LEFT JOIN instead of Inner Join:

```
SELECT settings.User_ID, 
  f1.Page_ID as Page_ID1, f1.Page_Title as Page_Title1,
  f2.Page_ID as Page_ID2, f2.Page_Title as Page_Title2,
  f3.Page_ID as Page_ID3, f3.Page_Title as Page_Title3,
  f4.Page_ID as Page_ID4, f4.Page_Title as Page_Title4,
  f5.Page_ID as Page_ID5, f5.Page_Title as Page_Title5,
  f6.Page_ID as Page_ID6, f6.Page_Title as Page_Title6,
  FROM mysettings s 
    left join cvl_pages f1 on s.fav1 = f1.Page_ID
    left join cvl_pages f2 on s.fav2 = f2.Page_ID
    left join cvl_pages f3 on s.fav3 = f3.Page_ID
    left join cvl_pages f4 on s.fav4 = f4.Page_ID
    left join cvl_pages f5 on s.fav5 = f5.Page_ID
    left join cvl_pages f6 on s.fav6 = f6.Page_ID
  where s.User_ID = 43;
```